# C segmentation fault when printing different things

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am currently making a few functions for a school project. When running each function alone and printing them, I have no errors, however when I print the result of all of the functions in main, I get a segmentation fault for the last function output.

My source code can be found [Here](https://github.com/danzam284/C-error-file/blob/main/hw1.c). This is the main segment which is not working:

```
int main() {
    char str1[] = "382 is the best!";
    char str2[100] = {0};

    strcpy(str1, str2);
    puts(str1);
    puts(str2);

    int vec_a[3] = {12,34,10};
    int vec_b[3] = {10,20,30};
    int dot = dot_prod((char*) vec_a, (char*) vec_b, 3, sizeof(int));
    printf("%d\n", dot);
    int arr[3] = {0x12BFDA09, 0x9089CDBA, 0x56788910};
    sort_nib(arr, 3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("0x%08x ", arr[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When running this code segment, I get the correct output for all except the final print loop, which I get a segmentation fault. However, if I comment out the puts statements and the printf(dot), the final print loop works.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Why do you have your own, incompatible version of `strcpy`?  It's incredibly misleading, since the standard library version (which you *should* be using) has the opposite argument order.  Don't redefine standard library functions.  Your implementation is also buggy, since it doesn't work on empty strings, and doesn't copy the terminating null character, so basically it's useless.

Comment: Why do you use labels and goto instead of normal loops? In your `sort_nib()` `a` is an array of 9 uninitialized pointers.

Comment: @TomKarzes Thank you for your comment and I understand what you are saying. The layout was created by my professor and if I were to change the function name, I would be given a 0 on the assignment.

Comment: @dimich Our class is transitioning to learning machine code so our professor requires us to use labels and goto rather than loops inside of our functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems with your code:

- Your custom `strcpy()` function is incorrect since it does not add a NULL terminator to the end of `dst`. Also the statement `dst[i] = src[0];` just copies the 0th element of `src` to the ith index of `dst`, which is incorrect. You have also use a `goto` statement instead of a loop which is confusing. Overall this functions logic is incorrect and makes no sense.

A better implementation would be:

```
void mystrcpy(char *dest, const char *src)
{
     while (*src) {
            *dest = *src;     // These lines can be
            dest++;           // Rewritten into one line:
            src++;            // *dest++ = *src++
     }

     *dest = '\0';
}
```

However you should consider not re-implementing standard library functions at all. This is because your implementation could be unsafe and erroneous (which it is). Furthermore these functions have been written by smart developers and are optimized and well thought out so its better to stick with them.

- The function `dot_prod` has a buffer over-read bug. In the following code:

```
int dot_prod(char* vec_a, char* vec_b, int length, int size_elem)
```

```
    PRODLOOP:
        if (i <= (length - 1) * size_elem) {
            int elema = (int) vec_a[i];
            int elemb = (int) vec_b[i];
            product += elema * elemb;
            i += size_elem;
            goto PRODLOOP;
        }
```

This is what you pass to `dot_prod()` in `main()`:

```
    int vec_a[3] = {12,34,10};
    int vec_b[3] = {10,20,30};
    int dot = dot_prod((char*) vec_a, (char*) vec_b, 3, sizeof(int));
```

As a result of this, you are accessing the 0th, 4th, and 8th element of `vec_a` and `vec_b` (assuming `sizeof(int)` is 4). The size of both arrays is 3 so the index range is from `0` to `2`.

- The `sort_nib()` function invokes undefined behavior in the following code:

```
char* a[9];
char* s;
int k = 0;

    CONVERT:
        if (k < length) {
            if (k == 0) {
                sprintf((char*) s, "%08X", arr[k]);
            } else {
                sprintf((char*) a, "%08X", arr[k]);
                s = combine(s, (char*) a);
            }
```

`s` is a uninitialized pointer and `a` is a array of pointers which are also uninitialized. So calling `sprintf()` on them invokes undefined behavior since they do not point to anything.

- Your `sort_nib()` function uses `goto` statements instead of loops which is quite confusing.